# How to delete a list from a list of lists with matching expression

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists like: list={{1,1,0},{2,1,1},{3,2,0},{4,2,4}};
I would like to remove the lists where list[[i]][[3]]=0 i.e. after removing those lists I will have an output i.e. {{2,1,1},{4,2,4}} removing list[[1]] and list[[2]]; Is there any way to manipulate a list in such fashion? Thanks in advance for help

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, {_, _, 0}, All]` or `DeleteCases[list, _?(#[[3]] == 0 &), 1]` or `Select[list, #[[3]] != 0 &]`

Comment: `list /. {_, _, 0} -> Nothing`

Comment: Thanks guys, all these solutions are working

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) or replacing with [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html), or [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), one could also use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[list, {_, _, z_} /; Abs[z] > 0]
```

or [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html)

```
Pick[list, Abs@Last[#] > 0 & /@ list]
```